# Angular ReferenceError: Controller is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I have a plunker here - http://plnkr.co/edit/ezKOtG9KJ6nD0068jpry?p=preview

I'm following this simple angular tutorial here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aG8VD0KvUw4

When I run the code a get ReferenceError: Controller is not defined

Can anyone explain this or who to fix it.

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('ShieldCtrl', function($scope){

            $scope.sheildNames = [];

            this.addReigns = function(){

                $scope.shieldNames.push('Reigns: One');

            };

            this.addCollins = function(){

                $scope.shieldNames.push('Collins: Two');

            };

            this.addAmbrose = function(){

                $scope.shieldNames.push('Ambrose: Three');

            };

        })


        .directive('theshield', function(){

            return{
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {},
                controller: 'ShieldCtrl',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                    element.bind('mouseenter', function(){

                        console.log(scope.sheildName);

                    })
                }
            }
        })


        .directive('reigns', function(){
            return{
                require: 'theshield',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ShielCtrl){
                    ShieldCtrl.addReigns();
                }
            }
        })

        .directive('collins', function(){
            return{
                require: 'theshield',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ShielCtrl){
                    ShieldCtrl.addCollins();
                }
            }
        })

        .directive('ambrose', function(){
            return{
                require: 'theshield',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ShielCtrl){
                    ShieldCtrl.addAmbrose();
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: your code has multiple issues causing it to not function correctly; the error you are asking about in this question is related to a simple typo:  `link: function(scope, element, attrs, ShielCtrl){`.  you are missing the `d` in all 3 functions.  Once you fix that, though, you have some other issues to work out with your logic.

Comment: I think controller is fine but for directive you maybe have to add app.directive at each directive.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple spelling mistake, your directive controller dependencies are ShielCtrl and you're trying to use ShieldCtrl.

```
    .directive('reigns', function(){
        return{
            require: 'theshield',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ShielCtrl){
                ShieldCtrl.addReigns(); <-- CHECK spelling.
            }
        }
    })
```

Your next error is another spelling error:  $scope.**sheildNames** = []; and you try to access the correct spelling:    $scope.**shieldNames**.push('Reigns: One');